# How Do I go about creating a Struct model after this JSON?

Tags: json, swift, codable

Here's my JSON:

https://pastebin.com/8HR6jcuC

Here is the model I've created though It failed to decode:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let results: [Order]
}

struct Order: Decodable {
    let charge_id: String
    let createdAt: String
    let items_bought : [BoughtItems]
    let objectId: String
    let soldBy: String
    let total: String
    let status: String
}

struct BoughtItems: Decodable {
    let price: Int
    let productTitle: String
    let quantity: Int
    let variantId: Int
    let variantTitle: String
}
```

Comment: And what is the error you get? and `total` seems to be a `Float`, not a `String`, but that's the kind of error that will be thrown in console giving you hints on what failed.

Comment: Shouldn't Order have a boughtBy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please catch the error and handle it. `Codable` errors are very descriptive.

> Type 'Int' mismatch: Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.
>
> codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "items_bought", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "price", intValue: nil)]

says clearly that `price` in `BoughtItems` is `String` rather than `Int`.

After replacing `let price: Int` with `let price: String` you will get another error

> Type 'String' mismatch: Expected to decode String but found a number instead.
>
> codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "total", intValue: nil)]

which is also very clear. The type of `total` is `Double`, not `String`

Fix: `let total: Double`

---

Please learn to **read** JSON. It's very simple:

- Everything in double quotes (**no** exception) is `String`
- Floating point numeric values are `Double`
- Other numeric values are `Int`.
- `true` or `false` (no double quotes) is `Bool`